# Create mutiple sharepoint folders from list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have an excel sheet with ~200 names, which I'd like to translate into folders in a SharePoint 2007 library. Is this possible with a simple copy/paste, or is there another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your intention with 200 folders in a list? If you're going to store data per name (within each of your folders) then I highly recommend the use of metadata columns rather than folders.

Comment: Different security levels per folder.

Comment: Right. Easiest way to do this then is with code in a console application - or PowerShell (which is slightly tricky in 2007 compared to 2010). If code is not an option, you can create 200 folders the hard way through the UI, create a Datasheet view, select the Title of the folder (might have to select a different column cell then arrow across to the folder), then Paste your names from your Excel column over the Folder Titles column. This might take a while to process though (~5mins).